# Order by sort order that is greater than 0

Tags: linq, c#-3.0

I am trying to sort a bunch of objects that have sort order, however some fields have been initialized to 0, so I want to first display all *users/objects* that have a **sort order** (in the actual correct order) then display then others e.g.

my list

```
{id:4,name:"Tom", sortoder:0}
{id:14,name:"Bee", sortoder:0}
{id:401,name:"Mike", sortoder:1}
{id:13582,name:"Monty", sortoder:2}
{id:55,name:"Charlie", sortoder:0}
{id:9,name:"Khan", sortoder:9}

        var fields = GetFields(myobject) //get fields (not really relevant)
                     .OrderBy(x => x.sortoder > 0) //this is where I am stuck on
                     .ToList();
```

My lists are all dislaying users with 0 at the top then those that have a sort order

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either use `ThenBy` to apply a second ordering after the first:

```
var fields = GetFields(myobject)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.SortOrder > 0)
    .ThenBy(x => x.SortOrder)
    .ToList();
```

Or you could use a conditional expression to replace the value 0 with `int.MaxValue` (assuming that int.MaxValue does not occur as a legitimate SortOrder):

```
var fields = GetFields(myobject)
    .OrderBy(x => x.SortOrder == 0 ? int.MaxValue : x.SortOrder)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: i doubt any numbers will ever be, but I really like this approach

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
.OrderBy(x => x.sortorder != 0 ? x.sortoder : int.MaxValue)
```

This basically means "treat 0 as a special value, equivalent to `int.MaxValue` - but otherwise just use the existing sortorder".

Mark's approach of first ordering by "have a sort order vs don't have a sort order" and then by the sort order value (which will obviously be 0 for the second group) would work fine too - it's really just a matter of personal preference which approach you use.

Comment: isn't it the other way around?

Comment: @JonSkeet - usually my objects are large (over 100-200) - my query is all in memory (i.e. get fields + sorting), what is the best your proposal or mark's?

Comment: @Jon, better now :), the solution could probably be cleaner if OrderBy took an IComparer"Delegate" instead of an interface. (I think you already wrote a helper for that purpose)

Comment: @Haroon: It's not clear what you mean by "over 100-200" - are you talking about the size of the *object* or the size of the *result set*? Either way, it's unlikely to make a significant difference.

Comment: @vc74: I don't see how it would be cleaner, to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement an IComparer or use a quick and dirty way like the following:

```
var fields = GetFields(myobject) //get fields (not really relevant)
                 .OrderBy(x => (x.sortoder == 0) ? int.MaxValue : x.sortoder) //this is where I am stuck on
                 .ToList();
```